# Spring WebFlux with Kafka and Websockets

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-webflux, spring-websocket

Right now I have a simple Kafka Consumer and Producer implemented in My SpringBoot application , which works fine what I wanna do next is that my consumer takes the consumed message and directly broadcasts it to all subscribed clients. I figured out that i can not use STOMP Messaging with WebFlux, so how can I accomplish this task , I saw the reactive WebSocket implementation but I did not figure out how I could send my consumed data to my websocket.

That is my simple KafkaProducer:

```
fun addMessage(message: Message){
        val headers : MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        headers[KafkaHeaders.TOPIC] = topicName
        kafkaTemplate.send(GenericMessage<Message>(message, headers))
    }
```

And my simple Consumer looks like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ["mytopic"], groupId = "test-consumer-group")
    fun receiveData(message:Message) :Message{
        //Take consumed data and send to websocket
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider to have a `Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer()` as global intermediate container. Then in your `receiveData()` you just *sink* data into that Reactor abstraction.

For your WebSocket connected sessions I would suggest to implement a `org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketHandler` and use `Sinks.Many.asFlux()` in the `WebSocketSession.send(Publisher<WebSocketMessage> messages)` API. This way all your sessions are going to consume the same Kafka data as long as they are connected to this WebSocket server.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-websockethandler

**UPDATE**

You can find some sample here: https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/so-65667450

Comment: Could you make an example?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: This really seems to work , could I somehow send an object to the websocket insted of a String?

Comment: An Object as a JSON

Comment: See `WebSocketSession.binaryMessage()`. The `Function` impl must take a ``WebSocketSession.bufferFactory()` as an argument and call `Jackson2JsonEncoder.encodeValue()` to get a `DataBuffer` back.